# Self Hosted Headless Codespace

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, codespaces

I am having trouble setting up self hosted headless codespace. I have been following the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/codespaces/how-to/self-hosting-cli. However when I get to the

```
codespace start
```

I get the following

```
$ codespaces start 
[2020-08-30 14:40:15.412 CLI.start I] Authenticating...
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code BUH36PN6G to authenticate.
[2020-08-30 14:40:37.196 CLI.start I] When connecting to this Codespace, you will be logged in as: ****
Would you like to run as a persistent service/daemon? [Y]/[n]: y
[2020-08-30 14:40:42.089 CLI.start I] Will register as a service/daemon
[2020-08-30 14:40:42.373 CLI.start E] [!ERROR] We could not find any subscriptions. Please create an Azure Subscription on https://azure.microsoft.com.
```

I have signed up with asure, have a subscription and set up a codespace plan. Is anyone else having these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is MS cutting off access to self-hosted codespaces without an announcement,
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vscodespaces/issues/775